# spark - scala - How can I check if a table exists in hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to check whether a table exists in hive using spark(1.6.2) scala

If it doesn't I have to create an empty dataframe and save that as a hive table.

If it exists, then overwrite the existing table.

I need a function that returns boolean based on which I could take the above mentioned decisions(of whether to create new table or overwrite existing one)

Comment: Actually, my spark version is 1.6.2 and I tried looking for the available methods in sqlContext class and I didn't find one.
Thanks for the above link. I see it has tableExists method, but didn't find spark.sql.catalog class for 1.6.2 version.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1.x:

```
def tableExists(table: String, sqlContext: SQLContext) =
  sqlContext.tableNames.contains(table)
```

2.x:

```
def tableExists(table: String, spark: SparkSession) =
  spark.catalog.tableExists(table)
```

2.1.x or later.

You can use `spark.catalog.tableExists`. Credits go to  [Huseyin Oktay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394863/huseyin-oktay) for [pointing that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477270/spark-scala-how-can-i-check-if-a-table-exists-in-hive/46477521?noredirect=1#comment87375102_46477521).

Comment: Bear in mind that you have to first `spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("database_name")`. A naive `spark.catalog.tableExists("database_name.table_name")` will not work.

Comment: I was able to find `tableExists` in spark `2.1.x` and above. Just FYI.

Comment: `spark.catalog.tableExists("database_name.table_name")` works for me in Spark 2.2.1 version.

Comment: I am using spark `2.1.0` and had to use `spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("database_name")` with `spark.catalog.tableExists("table_name")` <- note the db name is not present.

Comment: what is the pyspark (python) version?

Comment: PySpark unfortunately doesn't support `tableExists` functions directly [PySpark 2.1.1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/python/pyspark/sql/catalog.py) [Scala 2.1.1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.scala) However we can access to Java object and trigger that function manually by `spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists('db_name', 'table_name)`. More docs on Scala Catalog [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html)

Comment: spark.catalog.tableExists("myTableName") keeps giving me this error: py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public boolean org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl.tableExists(java.lang.String) is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl

Answer (score 5):

We also can define it with a database name as below.

1.6.x

```
sqlContext.tableNames("db_name").contains("tbl_name")
```

2.x:

```
spark.catalog.tableExists("db_name", "tbl_name")
```

Answer (score 2):

For spark 3.x Java the following worked for me

```
boolean isTablePresent = sparkSession.catalog().tableExists({db_name},{table_name});
```