# check if table exists in hive using spark 1.6 scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to check if a table exists in hive using spark 1.6 and scala coding.
i tried to explore over internet but couldn't find anything more useful than this

[spark - scala - How can I check if a table exists in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477270/spark-scala-how-can-i-check-if-a-table-exists-in-hive)

here it is mentioned that if we use

```
sqlContext.tableNames.contains("mytable")
```

then it returns boolean. but when i try this it checks in default database and gives me false.

how can i set a database to be looked into while this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the database first like this:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("use dbName")
```

and then search for the table:

```
scala> sqlContext.tableNames.contains("tabName")
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: in spark 1.6 we do not have "spark"... but when i tried like sqlContext.sql("db name ") and then sqlContext.tableNames.contains("tabName").. it worked.... thanks.. kindly edit your answer so that i accept it.

Comment: I've made the changes. Thanks.